# How to read data from landmarks files of Adience benchmark?

Tags: computer-vision, face-recognition, dlib

I'm trying to properly read the data corresponding to the landmarks files of the Adience benchmark, but I can't find an accurate way to parse them. Please can someone help me?

Comment: please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I think the actual question is implicit: How can i parse those files?

Comment: then please read [ask]. your question is too broad, you don't show any own efforts or research. you do not even specify a programming language...  and unless you are willing to wait for a miracle that someone comes by your question, who did the exact same thing you might want to provide more information so that anyone who has enough experience in similar things can help you without having to do 30 minutes of research on what you are actually talking about. I mean at least a link to such a file and that benchmark isn't too much to ask, is it?

Comment: If you read carefully, my question is about the Adience benchmark for gender and age estimation. In the website of this relatively new database [link] (http://www.openu.ac.il/home/hassner/Adience/data.html) they mention a Readme.txt, but this file is actually missing. This question is addressed to those researchers who have used this database and the landmarks files for scientific purposes and don't require any specific knowledge on no programming lenguaje, it is simply about parse a data file containing information of 68 landmarks points. If someone know, please share the answer.